# Attempt to install zend pdt in eclipse juno Java EE fails

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-pdt

I have read your how to install eclipse pdt in juno post. I exclude all options, eg. mylin, from the install but with repeated tries get the following:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.dltk,4.0.0.201206120848 No repository found
>   containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.dltk.console,4.0.0.201206120848 No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.dltk.console.ui,4.0.0.201206120848

This repeats itself for various repositories. I have the Juno Java EE all in one version.
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20121004-1855